# How do I get the first letter in each word in scala?

Tags: scala

If I have the phrase "New York City" how do I get the first letter of each word? My googling has only shown me how to capitalize the first letter in each word, which is seemingly different from what I'm trying to do.

Given my limited knowledge of Scala, I could probably do this procedurally but I was hoping someone could shed some Scala knowledge on me and show me an example that depicts a functional approach to this problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

All other versions work fine but in order to avoid failure with badly formatted strings (two blanks in a row, empty string), use

```
"New York City".split(" ").flatMap(_.headOption).mkString
```

which also works for

```
"New  York  City".split(" ").flatMap(_.headOption).mkString
```

or even

```
"".split(" ").flatMap(_.headOption).mkString
```

As suggested by [dhg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616589/how-do-i-get-the-first-letter-in-each-word-in-scala#comment18674162_13616757), one may want to use a more appropriate regex such as `"\\s+"` as well. But then one might just as well use something even more appropriate:

```
"""\w+""".r.findAllIn("New  York  City").map(_.head).mkString
```

(In here the `/\w+/` should hopefully spare us from pathological cases so we can go with the `.head` version.)

Comment: `"New  York  City".split("\\s+").map(_.head).mkString` accomplishes the same goal without the `Option`.

Comment: @dhg … but fails on the empty string.

Comment: you could filter out empty results, keeping just valid ones, which will allow you to use the `_.head` method: `"New York City".split(" ").filterNot(_.isEmpty).map(_.head).mkString`

Comment: I actually just had this issue with double spaces yesterday. So glad I came back and saw this. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

```
scala> "New York City".split(" ").map(_.head).mkString
res5: String = NYC
```

This splits by " " into an Array of words. Then we map over that array and call String.head which gets the first character.

Answer (score 5):

```
"New York City".split(" ").toList.map(_(0))
```

gives the characters:

```
List[Char] = List(N, Y, C)
```

If you want a string use `mkString` on the `List[Char]`:

```
"New York City".split(" ").toList.map(_(0)) mkString
```

to get:

```
String = NYC
```

Answer (score 4):

```
"New York City".split(" ").map(_.charAt(0))
```

Will give you a char array

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative to using split (Regex).

The trick here is to use zip to allow testing of the current and previous character in the same
iteration as you traverse the String, word boundaries consist of any letter preceded by a non-letter.

The two special cases, first and last letter, are handled by 1) prepending a space to a copy of the String which also sets up the 1 character skew required for the zip 
and 2) zip truncates partial pairs.

```
val s = "\n1New\n\t \t \tYork --City\n\t"


def firstLetters(s: String) = {
  " "+s zip s collect {case (w, c) if ! w.isLetter && c.isLetter => c}
}

firstLetters(s)
```

returns

```
Vector(N, Y, C)
```